# Black box appears after finishing a dialog activity

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog

For my app, I show a dialog under particular situations. Once clicking on OK, I see that this tiny black box appears for around less than a second, but can be clearly observed. It would seem as if it was lying under the Dialog Box.

I did some investigation using DDMS, but it only says that its class is android.widget.FrameLayout. It doesn't have any resource ID.

How can I figure out what this element is and how should I get rid of it ?

see snapshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
 dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

**OR**

You can try some theme on dialog ,with background transparent..
Something like this->

```
  <style name="DialogCustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

> set Background to layout  android:background;

```
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(CartActivity.this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().height =
                    (int) (Global.getDeviceMetrics(this).heightPixels*0.8);
           // dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_cart);
            TextView btn_Cancel = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
            TextView btn_ok1 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
```

> set dialog width and height based on screen.

```
public static DisplayMetrics getDeviceMetrics(Context context) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    display.getMetrics(metrics);
    return metrics;
}
```